# In an ng-repeat, is the iterator offset of $index dynamic to the results of a filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In an `ng-repeat`, is the iterator offset of `$index` dynamic to what is visible? I am getting seemingly incorrect `$index` values when a filter is applied.

Working with no filter applied:

[image]

Not appearing to work with filter applied (Note the console log):

[image]

When a filter is removed:

[image]

And finally my `ng-click` call:

```
<a ng-click="showHideOrderDropDown($index)" href="">
    Show More<br/><i class="icon-arrow-down"></i>
</a>
```

Click handler:

```javascript
$scope.showHideOrderDropDown = function(index) {
    console.log(index);
    $scope.data[index].orderDropDown = !$scope.data[index].orderDropDown;
};
```

Now I can easily work around this, but I was just hoping for some clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some research it appears that applying a Filter actually adds and removes (not hides) elements from the `ng-repeat` therefore the `$index` would apply to the new order of the array and no longer reflect the `$scope` array object.

Since asking the question I went ahead and passed the database id to the controller instead.

```
$scope.showHideOrderDropDown = function(id) {
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.data[i].id === id) {
            $scope.data[i].orderDropDown = !$scope.data[i].orderDropDown;
        }
    }
};
```